# Remove file name duplicates in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list `l`:

```
l = ['Abc.xlsx', 'Wqe.csv', 'Abc.csv', 'Xyz.xlsx']
```

In this list, I need to remove duplicates without considering the extension. The expected output is below.

```
l = ['Wqe.csv', 'Abc.csv', 'Xyz.xlsx']
```

I tried:

```
l = list(set(x.split('.')[0] for x in l))
```

But getting only unique filenames without extension

How could I achieve it?

Comment: How do you know whether to remove `Abc.xlsx` or `Abc.csv`

Comment: I need any one of the files, if I can remove any one it, whether it is a .xlsx or .csv. is fine

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am new to Py. I tried using split, but still I can't get the extension!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension that uses the name part as key and the full file name as the value, exploiting the fact that dict keys must be unique:

```
>>> list({x.split(".")[0]: x for x in l}.values())
['Abc.csv', 'Wqe.csv', 'Xyz.xlsx']
```

If the file names can be in more sophisticated formats (such as with directory names, or in the `foo.bar.xls` format) you should use `os.path.splitext`:

```
>>> import os
>>> list({os.path.splitext(x)[0]: x for x in l}.values())
['Abc.csv', 'Wqe.csv', 'Xyz.xlsx']
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the end result doesn't matter, we could split each item on the period.  We'll regard the first item in the list as the key and then keep the item if the key is unique.

```
oldList = l
setKeys = set()
l = []
for item in oldList:
    itemKey = item.split(".")[0]
    if itemKey in setKeys:
        pass
    else:
        setKeys.add(itemKey)
        l.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
l = ['Abc.xlsx', 'Wqe.csv', 'Abc.csv', 'Xyz.xlsx']
for x in l:
    name = x.split('.')[0]
    find = 0
    for index,d in enumerate(l, start=0):
        txt = d.split('.')[0]
        if name == txt:
            find += 1
            if find > 1:
                l.pop(index)
print(l)
```

Answer (score -1):

@Selcuk Definitely the best solution, unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to vote you answer.

But I would rather use `el[:el.rfind('.')]` as my dictionary key than `os.path.splitext(x)[0]` in order to handle the case where we have sophisticated formats in the name. that will give something like this:

```
list({x[:x.rfind('.')]: x for x in l}.values())
```

Comment: `I would rather use el[:el.rfind('.')]`: That would fail for filenames without an extension. Always use `os.path` to manipulate file names as there are many edge cases that you might not immediately think of.

Comment: It would actually be even better to use `pathlib` but yeah, the bottom line is never use string methods...

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for your comment, I missed the ones without extensions. Thanks